# Fixed effects and first differncing questions

Tags: regression, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

Let's say I am running the following regression:

$y_{i,t} = \beta x_{i,t} + \lambda_t + \eta_i + \epsilon_{i,t}$

where $i$ indices individual/county/group, $t$ time, $\eta$ and $\lambda$ are group and time fixed effects, and $\epsilon$ is the error term.

1. first assuming I have time period T>2. In cases with T=2, i know first differences yields equivalent estimates for $\beta$ as the fixed effect, but what about first differencing anyways with t>2? i.e. :

$\Delta y_{i} = \beta \Delta x_{i} + \Delta \lambda_t + \Delta\epsilon_{i}$

- is it true that this specification still is appropriate to purges the group fixed effect?

2. Say I have another specification as follows:

$y_{i,t} = \beta x_{i} + \lambda_t + \epsilon_{i,t}$

so here, the x variable only varies at the group level. Here, I obviously cannot include  group fixed effect  or else it would purge my x variable of interest. So, What if I just difference the dependent variable, and run the differenced y on the fixed x. would this be the correct way of writing this:

$\Delta y_{i} = \beta x_{i} + \Delta \lambda_t + \Delta\epsilon_{i}$

i.e., have I essentially purged a group fixed effect by doing this? Or is that an impossibility given the lack of time variation in x?

Comment: When T>2 FE and FD are not identical, but very similar for large samples. FD might have good performance when T is large and n is small (e.g. in macro panels).